# Does pjsip support application-specific RTCP packets?

Tags: pjsip, rtcp

I'm writing an application using pjsip and I need to receive application-specific RTCP packets. I'm looking at the implementation of `pjmedia_rtcp_rx_rtcp` (in [`pjmedia/src/pjmedia/rtcp.c`](http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk/pjmedia/src/pjmedia/rtcp.c)) and it only seems to handle certain RTCP packets and does not have a case for application-specific types. In case of an unknown packet type, it would just produce a `"Received unknown RTCP packet"` diagnostic message.

It looks like I may be able to install my own handler for received RTCP packets, using [`pjmedia_transport_attach`](http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMEDIA__TRANSPORT.htm#ga33a9285c010f2527e647f0b5871f881e). However, this would be called for *all* received RTCP packets, instead of just for application-specific ones. [Perhaps I could call the previous handler if it's not an app-specific packet, this needs further investigation.]

Is it possible to make pjsip call a callback on application-specific RTCP packets? And if not, how can I handle such RTCP packets while still using pjsip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although pjsip does not support application-specific RTCP packets directly, there is a way to capture all received RTCP packets and act upon those that are application-specific.

The first step is to create a [Media Transport Adapter](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Media_Transport_Adapter) which sits between the stream and the network transport (UDP). You can create and attach one of these in the `on_create_media_transport` callback.

Next, in your implementation of the `attach` callback, call `pjmedia_transport_attach()` passing your own callback functions for RTP and RTCP receiving, saving the original callbacks requested in the callback arguments. Exact details can be found in the `transport_adapter_sample.c` (see function `transport_attach`).

Finally, your implementation of the RTCP callback (`transport_rtcp_cb` in `transport_adapter_sample.c`) can do whatever it wants with the received RTCP packet before passing it on to the original callback.

Comment: Do we have any way / interface to achieve the same using `pjsua`?